# NDde implement DDE Server, Excel DDE can't update when server advise

Tags: excel, dde

theres
 I use [NDde](http://ndde.codeplex.com/) to create a DDE Server to support EXCEL client, 
 U use a timer to set item's value in the server periodically, 
 why Excel not change automatically when the item value changed ?
 But the first time the data will display when I input App|Topic!'item' in the cell
 Why ? any idea ?

Regards,
agichen

Answer (score 1):

Follow the examples included in the download. You will see that `DdeServer.OnAdvise` must be overriden to send data and that periodic calls to `DdeServer.Advise` must be used to notify clients.

Comment: No problem. Sorry for the late response. And remember I do not really maintain the library anymore so use at your own risk.